# Нужно ли ставить запятую после вводного слова перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Демократия, насколько известно(,) - политический режим, при котором единственным источником власти является народ...

Comment: Мне трудно иногда размышлять над вашими предположениями, уважаемые эксперты. Но я подразумевал данное предложение в качестве определения, связанного с такой наукой, как обществознание. Огромное вам спасибо, порой интересно читать, что вы пишите)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ДемокрАтия, **насколько извЕстно**, — политический режИм, при котором единственным источником власти является народ...*

1. Эта тема разбирается у Розенталя, и даже есть похожий пример: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Тире не ставится:  4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит **вводное слово**:  ***РИск, как извЕстно, // дело благорОдное;***

2. Казалось бы, в приведенном предложении должно быть **такое же решение** (обособляется двумя запятыми вводное сочетание, а **тире не ставится**), но **интонационно** оно не проходит. Мы не можем прочитать его без паузы, и это совершенно очевидно. Факт этот  надо обязательно учитывать, так как постановка тире (особенно в данной теме) обычно сопровождается наличием паузы.
3. **Но вот почему не читается?** Попробуем инверсировать определение (как у Розенталя): ДемокрАтия, насколько извЕстно, //режим политИческий... Да, теперь и без паузы читается нормально.
4. Вероятно, здесь следует различать **характер предложений**: логическое определение или оценка, характеристика, определение (у них разная расстановка логических ударений). В нашем случае это **логическое определение**, поэтому тире и пауза там **обязательны**.

Если же предложение содержит оценку, то при наличии вводного слова тире не ставится.

5. Постановка знаков в данном случае, скорее всего, **независимая,** по крайней мере, нет причин для отступления от этого правила.  Сказать, что вторая запятая после вводного сочетания может поглощаться тире, я как-то не решаюсь. В то же время разбора такого вида предложений нет, да и в текстах они встречаются редко.

Comment: Sharon, автор вопроса сомневается в запятой, а не в тире.

Comment: Автору,  вероятно,  важно правильно записать предложение, поэтому я объясняю все знаки. Возможно, он не знает, что в постановке тире при наличии вводного слова также надо сомневаться. Вводное сочетание обособляется, запятые никуда не денутся, а вот тире спорное. Это видно и по примеру из Розенталя. Но я считаю постановку тире обязательной, а не факультативной.

Comment: "*РИск, как извЕстно, // дело благорОдное;*" — нет, тут на первом слове нет ударения за счёт вводного элемента. Если есть ударение - то и есть тире.

Comment: Ну, это вы так думаете...  Не стоит желаемое выдавать за действительное. Проследите за произношением.

Comment: А, по-вашему, с/без тире ударения одинаковые? И в чём же тогда разница?

Comment: Мой дорогой друг, конечно же, ударения будут разные. А в чем разница - попробуйте разобраться сами.

Comment: Если у вас есть ударения без тире, то с тире они тем более должны быть. Так что не понятно, каким образом они разные.

Answer (score 5):

У Лопатина в справочнике:

> Наличие частицы *не*, а также вводных слов при устойчивых сочетаниях в роли сказуемого препятствует постановке тире (но не запрещает): Офицер этот не чета вам, господин жандарм (Фед.); Он у нас и ученый, и на скрипке играет, и выпиливает разные штучки, одним словом, мастер на все руки (Ч.).

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106

Так что запятая обязательна, т.к. это вводное предложение, а вот тире можно и  не ставить, но можно и оставить, как хотите. Я бы не ставила.

*Демократия, насколько известно, политический режим, при котором единственным источником власти является народ...*

Answer (score 1):

Свой комментарий я представлю как второй ответ, иначе его никто не заметит.

Вот ситуация. **Автор вопроса сомневается в постановке запятой**. И правильно делает, есть тут определенные сомнения. Но вот в постановке тире он не сомневается, а это тоже спорный вопрос.

Что делать? Наверное, **надо оба знака объяснить**, но... нельзя, не положено! Участники форума демонстрируют это мнение своим голосованием.

А что разрешается сказать? **Только про запятую.**

И никто не замечает, что такой пример разобран у Розенталя, и нет там никакого тире: *Риск, **как известно**, дело благородное.*

Но автор же спрашивал только про запятую... И предыдущий ответ я не считаю корректным. Цитирую: "...а вот тире можно и не ставить, но можно и оставить, как хотите. Я бы не ставила".

**Неужели это факультатив? Неужели на усмотрение автора?**

А что думают наши классики, а где реальные примеры? Сложная ситуация, надо бы обсудить, **но... нельзя, не положено!**

Опять же цитирую: "Sharon, **автор вопроса сомневается в запятой, а не в тире**".

Comment: Ну, чисто по-женски...

Comment: Просто не люблю голосование...